# Creating UI Image from Texture2D

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, unity-game-engine

I working on a live stream App that receives **JPEG** image as **arrays of bytes** and **displays** it on the **screen** with `UI.Image`. It **works** fine but I am making **optimization** and have **few questions**. Currently, the code I have below converts **arrays of bytes** to `Texture2D` then **creates** a `Sprite` from the `Texture2D` then assign that `Sprite` to `UI.Iamge` to display on the screen.

```
Texture2D camTexture;
Image screenDisplay;
public byte[] JPEG_VIDEO_STREAM;
bool updateScreen = false;
```

//Initializing

```
JPEG_VIDEO_STREAM = new byte[20000];
camTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
```

//Main Code that runs in the Update function

```
if(updateScreen){
camTexture.LoadImage(JPEG_VIDEO_STREAM);
Sprite tempSprite = Sprite.Create(camTexture, new Rect(0, 0, camTexture.width, camTexture.height), Vector2.zero, 0);
screenDisplay.sprite = tempSprite;
updateScreen = false;
}
```

The code above currently perform 3 steps just to display image to screen.

`byte array` **->** `Texture2D` **->** `Sprite` **->** `UI.Image`.

but I want it to look like `byte array` **->** `Texture2D`**->** `UI.Image`.

I want to write `Texture2D` directly to `UI.Image` **without** creating **new Sprite** because I believe that `Sprite.Create(camTexture, new Rect(0, 0, camTexture.width, camTexture.height), Vector2.zero, 0);` **allocates** new memory each time `Sprite.Create` called. I looked at the Unity Documentation and couldn't find any other way to do this.

My questions are:

1. How can I assign `camTexture(Texture2D)` to the screen `screenDisplay(UI.Image)` without converting `camTexture(Texture2D)` to `Sprite` first?
2. Does `Sprite.Create` allocate new memory when called?
3. If there is a **solution** to this, is that solution **better** than what I currently have in terms of **performance** and **memory management**?

Note: I have **no** plans on using `OnGUI` to draw `Texture2D`. I want to do this with the new Unity `UI`. Thanks.

**Edit:**
With Joe's answer of RawImage, the final code looks like this:

```
RawImage screenDisplay;
if(updateScreen){
camTexture.LoadImage(JPEG_VIDEO_STREAM);
screenDisplay.texture = camTexture;
updateScreen = false;
}
```

No more Sprite needed.

Comment: is there a chance to use `RawImage` here?

Comment: On the scene, the image I will be changing is a type of Image not RawImage. But if it is possible to cast RawImage or Image or even display RawImage directly to the screen then I am fine with it.

Comment: I just read this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1070280/raw-image-vs-image.html  and it looks like what I am looking for. Go ahead with your answer.

Comment: Thank God  .... can't wait to ßee how you implement this

Comment: related ?  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/940565/movietexture-in-ui-panel.html

Comment: I am not using MovieTexture but  your answer provides exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that by specifically using a `RawImage` rather than `Image`, one can do this.

I use `RawImage` extensively, because, we have to "display PNGs" and it's easier.

Consider the very handy trick:

just ***start with*** a trivial gray PNG which you have imported .. ***and then modify that*** .. rather than try to build from scratch?

An interesting curiosity I found is: normally to mirror an image, you just simply scale of x or y to -1.  Unless it's been fixed, Unity has a problem where this won't work for `RawImage`.

```
    // currently in Unity, the ONLY way to mirror a RAW image is by fooling with
    // the uvRect. changing the scale is completely broken.

    if ( shouldWeMirror )
      rawImage.uvRect = new Rect(1,0,-1,1); // means mirror
    else
      rawImage.uvRect = new Rect(0,0,1,1);  // means no flip
```

Another interesting factor. For this reason, many Unity projects still use (even 2017) the superlative **2dToolkit**. It instantly solves issues such as this.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted Image and created RawImage and that was it. Thanks for providing the mirror and flip stuff. The camera I am making this for supports commands to flip/mirrow the image but some others don't and your example will help implement that.